# Make both Python3 and Node available in same container

Tags: docker

I have a Dockerfile for dockerizing a Node.js app:

```
FROM node:carbon

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 80
CMD ["npm","start"]
```

But I also need to make Python 3 available. As I understand, multiple FROM statements in a Dockerfile will not work, as it only takes the most recent FROM. How can I make both Python3 and Node available inside the same container?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is true that you cannot use multiple `FROM` statements to get node from one base image and python from another.

What I would recommend is to settle on one base image and install the other application via the normal package manager. In general, installing Python 3 should be fairly straightforward, for example:

```
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y python3 && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Comment: RUN apt add --no-cache python3

Comment: @fins Thanks, I added the command. Have not set up docker properly on my current machine, but I'll test if it works with the node:carbon base image.

Comment: Getting E: Command line option --no-cache is not understood. I am running this on Mac.

Comment: `apt` still warns it doesn't have a stable CLI interface so `apt-get` is better for scripts.